# Is there a bound in Dafny on the number of recursive calls?

Tags: dafny

The following code verifies:

```
function stepMany(i : int, steps : int) : int
    requires steps >= 0;
    decreases steps;
{
    if steps > 0 then
        stepMany(i + 1, steps - 1)
    else
        i
}

lemma ex2()
{
    ghost var ex1 := 10;
    ghost var ex1Done := stepMany(ex1, 33);
    assert ex1Done == 43; // assertion verifies successfully
}
```

However, the following code does not verify:

```
function stepMany(i : int, steps : int) : int
    requires steps >= 0;
    decreases steps;
{
    if steps > 0 then
        stepMany(i + 1, steps - 1)
    else
        i
}

lemma ex2()
{
    ghost var ex1 := 10;
    ghost var ex1Done := stepMany(ex1, 34);     <-- only differences here
    assert ex1Done == 44;                       <-- and here
    // assertion DOES NOT verify
}
```

The only difference is the second parameter of stepMany. The assertion works for all arguments up to 33 and fails for all arguments exceeding 34.

Is there a maximum number of recursive calls Dafny can handle? I have tried searching the documentation and found nothing. There appears to be a command-line argument "/recursionBound", but it does not influence the results.

Answer (score 1):

The limit isn't so much on levels of recursion, but on levels of unfolding.  When Dafny has a recursive definition it will unfold it a bit.  But not without limit.

What you want is for Dafny to realize that `stepMany` is just an add function.  One way to do that is to write a lemma. Then you need to remind Dafny of what you told it by invoking the lemma.  Like this:

```
// Hey Dafny, the stepMany functions adds its arguments and returns the result.
lemma stepManyAddsItsArguments(i : int, steps : int)
requires steps >= 0
ensures stepMany(i, steps) == i+steps
decreases steps 
{} // Hey Dafny, would you mind proving that?

lemma ex2()
{
    ghost var ex1 := 10;
    ghost var ex1Done := stepMany(ex1, 34);
    stepManyAddsItsArguments( ex1, 34) ; // Heh Dafny, remember what I told you about stepMany!
    assert ex1Done == 44;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Right, in this case (minimized example) it is easy to summarize the function as the builtin "+" function. However, in the real example, there is no such closed form. Do you know if there is a way to change the unfolding level?

Comment: Indeed, the Dafny verifier unfolds function definitions a limit number of times (typically 1 time for functions in assume contexts, and 2 times for functions in assert contexts). Without such limits, attempts to prove something that doesn't hold would diverge. However, when the arguments (that play a role in the `decreases` clause) passed to the function are literals (like 34 in your example), then the verifier is willing to continue unfolding (almost) without limits. This "dual-rail encoding" is described in "Computing with an SMT Solver" by Amin, Leino, and Rompf, in TAP 2014: 20-35.

Comment: There is an experimental feature that lets you manually adjust these limits: the `{:fuel}` attribute. You can find some examples in `Test/dafny0/Fuel.dfy` in the Dafny test suite. Since this is an experimental feature, it may not always work like you'd expect or work at all. Thus, I would instead recommend Theo's proposed solution of using lemmas.